# MMs code for android

Tags: android

How to Attach video file to my application , and how to show video in videoview ?
have any idea about send sms with attached videofile means(mms) in android?
if possible , any body give me the Sample code about it??

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
sendIntent.setType("video/mpeg");
```

That should be all you need.